# How to show populations of abstract classes in index.gsp

Tags: grails

In Grails 4.0.3 and Grails 3.3.11, if you have an inheritance hierarchy with an abstract superclass, e.g.

```
package mypackage

abstract class A {
  String name
  // ...
  // properties
  // ...
}
```

```
package mypackage

class B extends A {
  String b
  // ...
  // properties
  // ...
}
```

```
package mypackage

class C extends A {
  String c
  // ...
  // properties
  // ...
}
```

And you populate the concrete classes in `Bootstrap.groovy`, e.g.

```
package mypackage

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        A.withTransaction { status ->
            def listOfB = []
            (1..25).each { i ->
                listOfB << new B(name:"b${i}",b:"${i}st")
            }

            B.saveAll( listOfB )

            def listOfC = []
            (1..25).each { i ->
                listOfC << new C(name:"c${i}",c:"${i}nd")
            }

            C.saveAll( listOfC )
        }
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

If you use scaffolding, the *index* page for `A` shows an empty list instead of a paginated list of 50 objects (25 B objects and other 25 C objects).

Apart from that, it shows a *new* button that generates a `java.lang.InstantiationException` when clicked because it tries to instantiate an abstract class.

How can I show populations of abstract classes in index.gsp?

Answer (score -1):

The workaround for this problem is the following:

1. Generate views for the abstract class (only `index.gsp` is relevant)
2. Edit the generated `index.gsp` in the following way:

   - Comment the *new* button code

```
<!-- no create button -->
<!--
<li><g:link class="create" action="create"><g:message code="default.new.label" args="[entityName]" /></g:link></li>
-->
```

- Comment the `<f:table>` element and add the following code

```
<!-- new arguments for f:table -->
<g:set var="collection" value="${mypackage.A.list(params)}" />
<g:set var="domainClass" value="${grailsApplication.getDomainClass('mypackage.A')}" />
<g:set var="domainProperties" value="${domainClass.getConstrainedProperties().keySet()}" />
<!-- old f:table -->
<!-- <f:table collection="${aList}" /> -->
<!-- new f:table -->
<f:table collection="${collection}" properties="${domainProperties}" />
```

With respect to `<f:table>` attributes:

- The `aList` variable originally passed to `<f:table>` is `null`.
- Do not include `domainClass="mypackage.A"`, it generates a `java.lang.InstantiationException`.
- The `properties` attribute must be present and contain the list of properties of the abstract class **only**. If it is not present, and objects of classes `A` and `B` appear in the same pagination, a `org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException` is thrown because `<f:table>` tries to read properties of class `B` on objects of class `C` and viceversa.

Apart from that, the `create` and `edit` pages are still available for `A`. I have `generated-all` for `A` and tried to delete those methods from the generated controller, but my knowledge of Grails is limited and I am having lots of errors with that, so I went back to scaffolding (which is my main reason for using Grails).

I think that Grails should not show empty lists for abstract classes in scaffolding, but I do not know if that behaviour is inside the scaffolding controller, the `<f:table>` tag, or harcoded in `_table.gsp`.

I also think that Grails should not generate `create` and `update` methods in the scaffolding controllers for abstract classes.

Comment: Posted as https://github.com/grails-fields-plugin/grails-fields/issues/307

Comment: This is really not a great idea.  Specifically, calling `A.list()` in the GSP is inconsistent with best practice and will be problematic under certain circumstances.  A better idea is to execute that query before the view is rendered and put the results in the model.

Comment: This is just a quick and dirty solution. To fix it properly, I guess that the scaffolded/generated controller and views (also service?) for abstract classes should be modified, but I do not know how to do that.